# Creating a search filter in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a user search for images, I have gone through the doc but I can't understand. I have installed Django-filter but I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 201, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 47, in list
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
  File "C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\python\instagram-clone\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 112, in get_serializer
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'
```

The goal is for users to search or filter posts by 'tags','owner' or 'image_url'

Comment model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=140, default="")
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='public/images', default='image.png')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='image.png')
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='img')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_uploaded',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

view.py

```
class PhotoSearchList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Photo
    serializer_class = PhotoFilterSerializer
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('tags', 'date_uploaded')
```

Serializer.py

```
class PhotoFilterSerializer(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('tags', 'date_uploaded')
```

urls.py

```
path('search/', views.PhotoSearchList.as_view()),
```

In the settings I added this as mentioned in the doc

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

I have also added `'django_filters'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the setting

Comment: As per the code snippet is given, the mentioned error won't get. Please add the error traceback

Comment: apart from that, the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) package provides proper documentation regarding the filtering and searching process

Comment: The error traceback is included

Comment: If you're using the searchfilter then you need to specify the `search_fields` not `filter_fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `PhotoFilterSerializer` is extending the wrong class. It's extending `FilterSet` when it should be extending `ModelSerializer`.

Change it to:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PhotoFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

If you wish to use a dedicated [`FilterSet`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) class, you could create a `PhotoFilter`:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class PhotoFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('tags', 'date_uploaded')
```

And then specify that separately on your view using the `filterset_class` attribute:

```
class PhotoSearchList(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    serializer_class = PhotoFilterSerializer
    filterset_class = PhotoFilter
```